# What is the mathematical name of the "curved space" in Einstein's theory?

Tags: mathematical-physics, math-history

Newtonian mechanics assumed a Euclidian geometry.

Einsteinian mechanics is based on non-Euclidian geometry.

However, there are many types of non-Euclidian geometry, so what is the mathematical name of the geometry used in Einstein's relativity theory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Riemannian geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_geometry) is the backbone of Einstein's General Theory of Relativity.

To quote, in his own words:

> "[In 1912] I suddenly realized that Gauss's theory of surfaces holds
>   the key for unlocking this mystery. I realized that Gauss's surface
>   coordinates had a profound significance. However, I did not know at
>   that time that Riemann had studied the foundations of geometry in an
>   even more profound way. I suddenly remembered that Gauss's theory was
>   contained in the geometry course given by Geiser when I was a
>   student... I realized that the foundations of geometry have physical
>   significance. My dear friend the mathematician Grossmann was there
>   when I returned from Prague to Zürich. From him I learned for the
>   first time about Ricci and later about Riemann. So I asked my friend
>   whether my problem could be solved by Riemann's theory , namely, whether the invariants of the line element could
>   completely determine the quantities I had been looking for."

**Albert Einstein**, as quoted by Abraham Pais in *Subtle is the Lord*,
 Pais's scientific biography of Einstein.

Comment: It should be noted that In General Relativity used **pseudo**-Riemannian metric. It has much more rich structure, just like Minkowski geometry have more rich structure than Euclidean.

Comment: @Corvus Yes, you are correct. Pseudo-Riemannian, as you say or, Semi Riemannian, as I knew it. Both make the same sense.

Comment: For the case of three space and one time dimension, or more generally, one time dimension, the term Lorentz or Lorentzian geometry is also quite common

Comment: @Thomas Yes, Lorentzian geometry, to be strict and specific, is the geometry behind the theory. And it is a special case of the riemannian geometry.